why my code is showing "boot button is not pressed" in smowcode while coding ESP32
The logic was correct and there were no problems or warnings when I uploaded the code but it wasn't compiled. I also followed the instructions and clicked the boot button while uploading it was displaying "upload failed"
I tried but the code wasn't uploaded to ESP32.

You should check if esptool.exe is accessible via your command prompt.
Steps to check that:

Press "win + R"
Write "cmd" and click ok.
Write "esptool" and click enter.
If you don't see anything, then go to start bar and type "env" to open environment variables settings.
In current/all users, find path named variable and edit it.
Add a new path pointing to "C:/smowcode/p" folder or the p folder inside your installation directory of Smowcode.

